# In rspec-rails the difference between "let" VS "let!"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I have googled this question but still not clear. I get that (:let) is lazily evaluated and will never be instantiated if you don't call it, while (:let!) is forcefully evaluated before each method call.

```
let(:article) = { Article.new(name: 'article1') }
let!(:article) = { Article.new(name: 'article1') }
```

Can any body explain it more and what are the benefits of using let!

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you want the indirect results of the `let` to be present.

For example...

```
let(:article) = { Article.create(name: 'article1' }

it "does not add an article with a duplicate name" do
  expect(Article.create(name: article.name)).not_to change(Article.count)
end
```

This would actually fail, because the `Article.count` before the test will not include the `article` object because it's not yet created, not until it's referenced.  So even though the new article (the one with the duplicate name) is not created, the test will still detect a change to `Article.count`

Now, if you do...

```
let!(:article) = { Article.create(name: 'article1' }

it "does not add an article with a duplicate name" do
  expect(Article.create(name: article.name)).not_to change(Article.count)
end
```

The `article` object will already exist in the `Article.count` before the `expect` and the test will pass.